# Most repeated value in a Card visual using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to return the most repeated ID in a table, inide a Card visual in Power BI.

I've tried the following:

```
test = 
FIRSTNONBLANK(
    TOPN(
        1,
        VALUES(
            Sales[Customer ID]
        ),
        RANKX(
            ALL(
                Sales[Customer ID]
            ),
            COUNTX(
                Sales,
                Sales[Customer ID]
            ),,
            ASC
        )
    ),
    1
)
```

This measure returns the following:
[Card Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gI4h.png)

However, this is not the most repeated value. When I add an ID count in a table, I see this:
[ID count table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epkna.png)

When I order by the ID count, it tells me that the most repeated ID is WB-21850.
[Table showing the right ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igkNP.png)

I don't know what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Most Repeated Customer ID = 
var t = ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(Sales, Sales[Customer ID]),
    "@qty", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sales))
)

var rtn = MAXX(TOPN(1, t, [@qty], DESC), Sales[Customer ID])

return rtn
```